# Compare order of columns between two databases

Tags: postgresql, schema

I  have two postgres databases which should have an equal db-schema, but have not.

I want to see the difference in the column order.

Columns of table1 in Dev: id, foo, bar

Columns of table1 in Prod: id, bar, foo

**Strategy 1: list of columns**

This is my current strategy to solve this.

Dump all columns of the database like this:

```
table1.id
table1.foo
table1.bar
table2.id
table2....
```

If I have a simple ascii list of both sides, I can use a diff tool to compare both db schemas.

I found ways to output all columns like above but the solutions don't support ordering by the schema of the table.

**Question**

How to show the difference of the column order in two databases?

Other strategies are welcome.

Implementation: I use postgres 9.3

Comment: The order of columns in a table is irrelevant (which is one of the reasons `select *` is bad coding style). Why do you need to verify this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is, usually, except the cases where the gaps produced by alignment are costly enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have legacy code which does `INSERT INTO phone_book VALUES ('John Doe', '555-1212');`. Here the order of the columns is relevant.

Comment: Which is even worse than `select *` - you have my sympathy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If I have a simple ascii list of both sides, I can use a diff tool to compare both db schemas.*

To get a list of all table columns you can use something like this:

```
select concat_ws('.', table_schema, table_name, column_name) as column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
order by table_schema, table_name, ordinal_position;
```

Of course you can limit that to the schema(s) you are interested in.

You can use psql's `\copy` statement to spool that to a file. Or use whatever export feature the SQL client you are using offers you.

Comment: `order by .. ordinal_position` that col was new to me. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Just for the records. Next step would be to call this on remote and local and compare the result. Since quoting quotes can be non trivial in the shell I search for a cleaner solution: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26377/compare-script-output-from-remote-server-with-local-result

Comment: @guettli: the easiest solution is to not use the `-c` switch, but to store the statement in a file and use `-f foo.sql`

Comment: yes, this works for psql. But in my softwarerec question I search something which works for more then psql. I have very simple solution in my mind. But I wait. Maybe someone has a better idea :-)